# ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit not shown in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have downloaded the AJAX Control Toolkit. I created a new tab in VS 2008 (SP1) toolbox, added the controls from the AjaxControlToolkit.dll, everything went fine. When I removed the toolbox and tried to perform the same steps as above, it didn't work anymore.

That is, in the window shown for the "Choose items", the controls aren't automatically added to the list, as before.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.. a restart of the machine solved the problem; maybe issuing "devenv /resetsettings" before that was of help.